# panic: http: multiple registrations for /static/

Tags: go

Please consider this problem:

I've to launch multiple listeners on unique ports,  like:

```
function launchUI(self *myObject) {
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir(self.staticFs))
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))
    go http.HandleFunc("/login", self.loginHandler)

    errx := http.ListenAndServeTLS(self.uiport, self.cert, self.key, nil)
    if errx != nil {
        fmt.Println("http Listen err", errx)
        panic("http Listen")
    }
}

listOfObjects := []*myObject{} 
for _, obj := range(listofObjects){
     obj.launchUI()
    <snip>
}
```

Each of these are on unique `self.uiport` and I must serve `/static/` and `/login` for each object. Pretty straightforward stuff. Except, if my `listOfObjects` have multiple items in it, this blows up:

```
panic: http: multiple registrations for /static/ 

goroutine 7 [running]:
net/http.(*ServeMux).Handle(0x4da250, 0x2b8830, 0x1, 0x324f68, 0x12183a8)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2403 +0x278
net/http.(*ServeMux).HandleFunc(...)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2440
net/http.HandleFunc(...)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2452
main.(*userStruct).startUI(0x10d6160)
```

Could you please show me how to fix this?

Comment: Create a [new mux](https://godoc.org/net/http#NewServeMux) for each listener instead of using the [default mux](https://godoc.org/net/http#DefaultServeMux).

Comment: Not related to your problem, but `go http.HandleFunc("/login", self.loginHandler)` suggests that your choice to use the `go` keyword is arbitrary rather than informed, since in your use case it is anything but useful. I'd recommend you skip using it unless you're certain you actually need it.

Comment: Thank you. So I know, could you please explain to me why launching `go http.HandleFunc` is unneeded? What harm does it cause, if any?

Comment: The `go` keyword spins up a new goroutine so that the associated function can be executed concurrently, i.e. you use it when you *need* concurrency, and, conversely, when there's no need for concurrency, as is the case with the code under discussion, you don't use it. Ultimately there's no harm done (that I'm aware of), your code will work just as well with as without the keyword, I'd argue however, that it *is* bad style, just like it would be with anything used for the wrong purpose, if any at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```golang
function launchUI(self *myObject) {
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir(self.staticFs))
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))
    mux.HandleFunc("/login", self.loginHandler)

    errx := http.ListenAndServeTLS(self.uiport, self.cert, self.key, mux)
    if errx != nil {
        fmt.Println("http Listen err", errx)
        panic("http Listen")
    }
}
```